# Creating a bubble map from custom GeoJson with Highcharts / Highmaps

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use Highmaps with a custom GeoJson, in order to have bubbles appear on my map.

I got [error #22](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/22) so I followed the instructions [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/latlon) (there's also an example of what I'm trying to achieve)

I installed [proj4](http://proj4js.org/) in my Angular app (and proj4js as well, but I got the warning : `proj4js@10.0.0: please use 'proj4' instead, proj4js is not maintained`). The installations seemed to work without any problem.

However, now I still get an [error #21](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/21) from Highmaps, and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

After hunting down obscure Google results, here is what I did to stop getting this error :

I added this in my GeoJson :

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"hc-transform": { // this part
    "default": {
        "crs": "a string defined like in Proj4 examples... I'm still struggling with it, to be honest"
    }
},
...
```

At the beginning of my Angular component file :

```
var proj4 = require('proj4');
```

And inside my Angular component :

```
ngOnChanges() { // it doesn't matter where you put it,
    if (!window['proj4']) { // as long as it happens before any Highmaps-related work
        window['proj4'] = proj4.default;
    }
}
```

This solution was inspired by this result : https://gist.github.com/jon-a-nygaard/9437aad5d03c11c8c65604e4e7fba34b

Maybe this will help somebody in the future. Cheers !